# Algolia style API documentation

Tags: documentation-generation, algolia

I really like the way Algolia has approached their multi-programming language API documentation, e.g. https://www.algolia.com/doc/javascript .

Does some know by chance what technologies do they use to generate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation generator we're using is currently an internal tool. We might open-source it at some point, but it would require some extra work time which we don't currently have.

It's basically a markdown file with some extra syntax to:

- handle multiple languages code blocks (it then automatically selects the good one)
- handle conditions depending on the current language
- handle callouts
- handle buttons

The rendering is then hand-made with the help of bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response :)